# Vector Space of Lie Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

Lie algebra $ \mathfrak{g} $ for a Lie group $ \mathcal{G}$ is closed under commutation. Also, the elements of Lie Algebra form a Linear Vector Space(LVS).

Firstly, when is it allowed to define an Inner product (IP) in this vector space ? What is the characteristic of a Group for which I can't define and IP for the corresponding Lie algebra ? (I have heard about this Killing form, but not understood it completely).

Secondly, if I now define a LVS with IP, then there has to be a metric for this space (so is it a metric space ? it seems like yes !!). If there is a metric, I can again define a set of transformations that will leave the metric (or line element) of the space invariant, am I right ? (Again, I think I am referring to Casimir elements of the group, but I am not sure).

**PS** :I am sorry if these questions are silly. I am a physics student, and hence not able to get a concrete mathematical structure of these things. I would be quite happy if the answer is a little physics(sy).

Comment: "I am a physics student, and hence not able to get a concrete mathematical structure of these things." Do you think that physics students don't have to learn maths properly or aren't able to? I encourage you to learn mathematics rigorously first, and then understand the physical motivation behind it.

Comment: @Turion : I am trying to do that all the time, and the sole reason why I posted the question here and not Phys.SE. But my point was to make sure that notationally I should be able to understand, and not concerning the rigor. I would be happy to get rigorous answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly $\kappa (x,y)=tr (ad (x)ad(y))$ is the Killing form, where $ad(x)y=[x,y]$. It is a symmetric bilinear form. In characteristic zero it is non-degenerate if and only if the Lie algebra is semisimple. For nilpotent Lie algebras, for example, the Killing form is just zero. But speaking of physics, the Heisenberg Lie algebra is nilpotent. 
Secondly, semisimple Lie algebras with this inner product become a metric space, yes. There a re several good books with the title "Lie Groups and Lie Algebras for Physicists", which give you much more background.

Comment: +1, Thanks for that insight about Heisenberg algebra. I was wishing somebody would clarify that !!

Comment: Can you please describe whatever you have said in mathematical language, it would be quite very helpful. I mean define the things that you have said mathematically !!!

Comment: OK, Killing form I defined above. For the definition of a Lie algebra, or nilpotent and semisimple, see wikipedia, or a book on Lie algebras.